# Dell Lat E6500 Alps touch pad strange problem

Tags: 20.04, dell, touchpad, alps

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
so when the buttons are set to "right handed" all works well except two finger "right click" when I switch to "left handed" all works well except that the "tap to click"  function now becomes a "right click", instead of a "left click" as expected.

Any one have this problem and were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed I never answered my own question and I did find a solution!

add the following line to /etc/rc.local before the "exit 0" line.

```
#fix click on the touchpad for left-handed mouse setting, comment out if set to right-handed.

synclient tapbutton1=3
```

now when the system starts and if the touchpad is set to left-handed the pad will click on tap!